# Plugin 0 specified in babel-preset-es2015 provided an invalid property of _c

Tags: babeljs

Getting above error with below configuration, commenting passPerPreset removes the error however. Is there any configuration missing ?

.babelrc :

```
{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "presets": [{
      "plugins": [
        "./build/babelRelayPlugin",
        "transform-runtime",
        "transform-es2015-classes"
      ]
    }, "es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
  "env": {
     "development": {
      "presets": ["react-hmre"]
    }
  }
}
```

package.json :

```
"babel-cli": "^6.5.1",
"babel-core": "^6.5.2",
"babel-eslint": "^4.1.8",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
"babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes": "^6.5.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.5.2",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
"babel-relay-plugin": "^0.7.0",
"babel-runtime": "^6.5.0",
```

Webpack :

```
module: {
    loaders: [        
    {
      loader: "babel-loader",
      include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "app"),
      ],
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      query: {
        plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
      }
    },
  ]
```

},

Error : babel-node start

```
Module build failed: Error: Plugin 0 specified in "/Users/my/demo/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/index.js" provided an invalid property of "_c"
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: m currently having "passPerPreset" disabled, need to revisit some examples in github and check my configuration..

Comment: The order in which you specify the presets matter for babel. It should be "react", then "es2015" and then "stage-0". You have it right in your webpack.config, but not in your .babelrc and your .babelrc is taking precedence.

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me was:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm prune
npm cache clear
npm cache clean
npm i
```

Answer (score 6):

Upgrading `babel-core` and `babel-loader` fixed this for me.

```
npm install --save babel-core@latest babel-loader@latest
```

Comment: Likewise. I think everyone else who's deleting their `node_modules` is just getting a newer version of these packages when reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there might be contention between what you've specified in `.babelrc` and what you've configured in `babel-loader`.

Can you try to remove the `query` from your Webpack config?

Comment: after commenting query section in webpack.config.js gives same error

Comment: only if passperpreset is commented in .babelrc, it completes successfully

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but removing and rebuilding node_modules as Alex suggested didn't help in my case.

It turned out that there was some version mismatch with may packages. When I deleted all the *dependencies* and *devDependencies* from `package.json` and added them again by `npm i -S` or `npm i -D` respectively, everything started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing my `node_modules` etc didn't work. However, commenting-out `passPerPreset` did the trick. TBH I'm not really sure what that option does, but most of the google hits on it are bug reports, so I'm fine so long as it works.

```
// babelrc
{
  //"passPerPreset": true,
  "presets": [
    "stage-0",
    "react-app"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    "syntax-async-functions",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "react-relay"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating my npm version solved this problem.